# Web Developer 2010 Express does not list 4.0 framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Whatever I do for several days now, Web Developer 2010 Express does not see 4.0 NET Framework. If to right click on solution properties in the Application – Target Framework it lists 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5, which are NOT installed on my computer but 4.0 which is actually installed. I tried to clean all using dotnetfx_cleanup_tool, reinstalled 4.0 client and full several times, copied reference assemblies to different folders and so on but WDE still does not see it.

I also have SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 installed.

Where and how does it find frameworks, does in scan registry or some config file?

Answer (score 0):

To target .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5, you have to install .NET 3.5.

And Web Develoepr requires full profile, not client profile.

Comment: It is natural to target .NET 4.0 when Web Developer 2010 is installed